# Refresh widgets when selecting other radiobutton

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a small application where you can insert the dimensions of a cross section and then properties as area, moments of inertia, etc. will be calculated.

The problem is that I want to refresh the 'section dimensions' each time I select another radiobutton, but now it just overwrites. I know my code looks quite amateurish but I am trying to make it look more professional.

```
#Import modules
from tkinter import *

# Create application box
root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x600+0+0")
root.title("Predefined cross-sections beams")

# Define variables
height = StringVar()
width = StringVar()
diameter = StringVar()
thickness = StringVar()
flangethickness = StringVar()
webthickness = StringVar()
standinglegthickness = StringVar()
lyinglegthickness = StringVar()
area = StringVar()
i2 = StringVar()
i3 = StringVar()


## Solid rectangular section
# Dimensions and properties
def rectangle(*args):

    H = float(height.get())
    B = float(width.get())

    #while H <= 0 or B <= 0 :

    area.set(H * B)
    i2.set(B**3 * H / 12)
    i3.set(B * H ** 3 / 12)

# Layout
def rect():
    Label(root, text="Section height").grid(column=0,row=12)
    Label(root, text="Section width").grid(column=0,row=13)
    Label(root, text="").grid(column=0,row=14)
    Button(root, text="Calculate",command=rectangle).grid(column=0,row=15)
    Label(root, text="").grid(column=0,row=16)
    Label(root, text="Area: ").grid(column=0, row=17, sticky=W)
    Label(root, text="I2: ").grid(column=0, row=18, sticky=W)
    Label(root, text="I3: ").grid(column=0, row=19, sticky=W)

    Entry(root, textvariable=height).grid(column=1,row=12)
    Entry(root, textvariable=width).grid(column=1,row=13)

    Label(root, text="m").grid(column=3,row=12)
    Label(root, text="m").grid(column=3,row=13)

    Label(root, textvariable=area).grid(column=1,row=17)
    Label(root, textvariable=i2).grid(column=1, row=18)
    Label(root, textvariable=i3).grid(column=1, row=19)

## Solid circular section
# Dimensions and properties
def circle(*args):
    D = float(diameter.get())

    #while H <= 0 or B <= 0 :

    area.set(pi * D**2 / 4)
    i2.set(pi * D**4 / 64)
    i3.set(pi * D**4 / 64)

# Layout
def circ():
    Label(root, text="Section diameter").grid(column=0,row=12)
    Label(root, text="").grid(column=0,row=14)
    Button(root, text="Calculate",command=circle).grid(column=0,row=15)
    Label(root, text="").grid(column=0,row=16)
    Label(root, text="Area: ").grid(column=0, row=17, sticky=W)
    Label(root, text="I2: ").grid(column=0, row=18, sticky=W)
    Label(root, text="I3: ").grid(column=0, row=19, sticky=W)

    Entry(root, textvariable=diameter).grid(column=1,row=12)

    Label(root, text="m").grid(column=3,row=12)

    Label(root, textvariable=area).grid(column=1,row=17)
    Label(root, textvariable=i2).grid(column=1, row=18)
    Label(root, textvariable=i3).grid(column=1, row=19)

# Create radiobuttons
var = IntVar()
Radiobutton(root, text="Rectangle", variable=var, value=1, command=rect).grid(column=0, row=2, sticky=W)
Radiobutton(root, text="Circle", variable=var, value=2, command=circ).grid(column=0, row=3, sticky=W)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: So you want to update some widgets based on when a radiobutton is selected?

Comment: Yes exactly, I want to make the corresponding input dimensions appear: diameter for a circle, height and width for a rectangle, height, width, flange and web thickness for an I-shape etc. Now they do appear but they overwrite each other. So I think I need some kind of destroy/clear function every time someone selects a(nother) button.

Comment: PS: I only showed the code with rectangle and circle now, but I have all the other common sections (tube, box, I-shape, tee, channel, angle) coded in the same way.

Comment: I think I found a solution: I wrapped all the displaying widgets in a frame and every time a radio-button is selected, the frame is destroyed and created again. Is there a better way to do it?